Puppeteer cant listen all request from paribu.com
I want to listen all request ( with data ) from paribu.com; but i listen only some request without request data.
Etc. i see only this when i use sign ( and i dont unsterstand why i see same request two times ):
https://www.paribu.com/auth/sign-in
https://www.paribu.com/auth/sign-in
Note :I see websocket received messages .
I want to set alarm for "bitcoin" again i see only :
"https://www.paribu.com/alarm".
The website is created entirely with JavaScript and sends data via websocket. But I couldn't figure out how the data is sent to the website. For example, when I want to log in, I can only see the paribu.com/auth/sign-in link on the log page. I can't see what else is being sent. I also want to make something like WhatsApp bot js. It will set automatic coin alarm and make automatic coin sales. Currently I can only process with incoming data.
var puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.paribu.com");
  const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1080, height: 1024});
  await cdp.send("Network.enable");
  await cdp.send("Page.enable");

  const printResponse = function (response) {
    console.log("response: ", response);
  };

  cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameReceived", printResponse); // Fired when WebSocket message is received.
  cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameSent", printResponse); // Fired when WebSocket message is sent.

  page.on("request", request => {
    console.log(request.url());
  });

  page.on("response", response => {
    console.log(response.url());
  });
}

run();


The reason it doesn't work is because you are listening to the request after the page already loads and created websocket connections. If you start listening to the network before navigating to the page, it should work.

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run() {
    // Launch the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Create a CDP session to listen to network events
    const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await cdp.send("Network.enable");
    await cdp.send("Page.enable");

    // Function to log WebSocket messages
    const logWebSocketMessage = (eventType, message) => {
        console.log(`${eventType}: `, message);
    };

    // Set up listeners for WebSocket frames
    cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameReceived", (params) => logWebSocketMessage("Received", params));
    cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameSent", (params) => logWebSocketMessage("Sent", params));

    // Set up listeners for HTTP requests and responses
    page.on("request", request => {
        console.log("Request URL: ", request.url());
    });

    page.on("response", response => {
        console.log("Response URL: ", response.url());
    });

    // Navigate to the target page
    await page.goto("https://www.paribu.com");
    
    // Set viewport size
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });
}

// Execute the script
run();

To your other questions, you see two requests in console, because you wrote the code that way; you are printing both request and response, so it prints once for the outgoing request and another for the incoming response.
You can access the data inside the request and response using various methods listed on their official doc. Here is the link to Request related api documentation.

I can get the data as you did; but for example: when I try to log in I can't see what data is going.

Unfortunately it's not possible for me to test this as a logged in user due to the lengthy signup process and requirements. If you have some other ways to debug this, I will be happy to help.

You do not need to register, we can find out what data was sent if you entered it incorrectly.
